# Python prefix filename with parent folder name while copying files to a new destination

Tags: python, python-3.x

I appreciate anyone assisting me with this, I am very new to programming and Python.
My situation is that I have some files that are in different subfolders.
I would like to copy the files over to a new destination but prefix the copied filenames with the source parent or grand parent folder name. My below code copies the files over no problem:

```
import os
import shutil

source = r'/Volumes/Folder1' + '//'
dest = r'/Volumes/Folder2' + '//'

for path, dir, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:

        if "red" in file.lower():
            shutil.copy2(path + '//' + file, dest + file)
```

**but when I try to add the source folder name to the existing code like below, I get an error:**

```
for file in files:
  foldername = path.split("//")[-1]
    if "red" in file.lower():
        shutil.copy2(path + '//' + file, dest + file)
```

I know for a fact that I am not going about this the right way, I feel like i have to use os.join or something. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)

Comment: @HåkenLid I will look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple code for you:

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(os.path.join(path , file),os.path.join(dest , file))
```

Reading your code I wonder why there is "//".
Usually a "/" is enough, but you don't need to worry about it, use `os.path.join`

Comment: thanks man but unfortunately I get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/python_work/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    copyfile(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(dest, file))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Volumes/Folder1/basicred.txt'

Comment: "No such file or directory: '/Volumes/Folder1/basicred.txt'". Please pass an absolute path.

Comment: This error is caused by you incorrectly passing the path of the files.

Comment: thanks man, that solved it. I wasn't understanding how cwd's worked.